# Optimize Query with MAX/MIN in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query that is taking 17-20 seconds on our server, and I'd like to see what I can do to optimize it. MySQL 5.6, will be upgrading to 5.7 next couple of months.

Query:

```
SELECT pm.mid AS mid
FROM 
pm_message pm
INNER JOIN pm_index pmi ON pmi.mid = pm.mid
GROUP BY pm.mid
HAVING  (MIN(pmi.deleted) > 0 AND MAX(pmi.deleted) < '1535490002') 
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0;
```

The mid column in both pm_message and pm_index is a primary key in both tables.
The table have millions of records each

```
select count(*) from pm_message;
3748290

select count(*) from pm_index;
6938947
```

Any suggestions for improving this query?

I'm wondering if making the 'deleted' column in the pm_index table an index would help?

Comment: You may try to add an index on `pm_message.mid` and/or `pm_index`.

Comment: the mid column is primary key in both tables.

Comment: You can try an index on `pm_index (mid, deleted)`. If you're on version 8.0 maybe even two: One on `pm_index (mid, deleted ASC)` and one on `pm_index (mid, deleted DESC)`. And (most likely) unrelated: If `deleted` is not a string, but a numeric, remove the single quotes around `1535490002`.

Comment: @sticky bit, still on mysql 5.6, fixing to be upgrade to 5.7 this year. deleted column is an int, so I can do that...I'll try both your suggestions.

Comment: If _mid column in both pm_message and pm_index is a primary key in both tables_ then what is the purpose of group by? It will always be one row per mid after join.

Comment: The min and max are quite cryptic; please explain the intent.  Perhaps it has to do with groupwise max?

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: @stickybit - when comparing a numeric column to a literal, it does not matter whether the literal is a sting or not.  The opposite does matter -- `VARCHAR` versus an unquoted number will be inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I would completely rewrite the query because you basically want a list of distinct mids where deleted falls within a certain range. You do not need to display any data from the `pm_index` table, so I would use correlated subquery with `not exists` operator. This way mysql does not have to group and order the entire `pm_index` table to get the mins and the maxes.

```
SELECT pm.mid AS mid
FROM 
pm_message pm
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pm_index WHERE pm_index.mid=pm.mid and (pm_index.deleted<0 OR pm_index.deleted>1535490002))
```

The query would benefit from a multi-column index on mid and deleted fields of `pm_index` table.

Comment: Wouldn't mysql optimiser rewrite this to the plan very close (if not identical) to `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @zerkms if mysql wants to express the above with join, then it will most likely be an anti join as opposed to an inner one.

Comment: Oh right, that `NOT` for some reason got into my blind spot.

Comment: to match my original query, shouldn't the greater than / less than signs be opposite for the deleted column in your example?

Comment: @jackrabbithanna you have also missed the `not` keyword :)

Comment: This query returns results, much faster, even without adding the (mid, deleted) index...like in less than a second. I'm a little confused now because the original query posted here doesn't return any results...I'm trying to figure out if it's because it's just timing out or if there is some difference in the query you have posted.

Comment: The logic of my query is a bit twisted compared to your version. However, in SQL you often need twisted logic to get results fast :) Nevertheless, the exclusion criteria are same in our queries.

Answer (score 1):

This elaborates on Shadows answer.  Try using two `not exists` clauses:

```
SELECT pm.mid 
FROM pm_message pm
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM pm_index pmi
                  WHERE pmi.mid = pm.mid AND 
                        pmi.deleted < 0
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM pm_index pmi
                  WHERE pmi.mid = pm.mid AND 
                        pmi.deleted > 1535490002
                 ) ;
```

And be sure you have an index on `pm_index(mid, deleted)`.  The index is very important.  I'm breaking it into two clauses because `OR` can confuse the query optimizer.

Comment: to match my original query, shouldn't the greater than / less than signs be opposite for the deleted column in your example?

Comment: @jackrabbithanna . . . No.  You are looking for values within that range.  Hence, there should be no rows with values outside that range.

Comment: This query returns results, much faster, even without adding the (mid, deleted) index...like in less than a second. I'm a little confused now because the original query posted here doesn't return any results...I'm trying to figure out if it's because it's just timing out or if there is some difference in the query you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  It turn things inside out -- starting with pmi, then minimizing touching of pm.

```
SELECT  mid, MIN(deleted) AS mind, MAX(deleted) AS maxd
    FROM  pm_index AS pmi
    GROUP BY  mid
    HAVING  mind > 0
      AND  maxd < '1535490002'
      AND  EXISTS (
            SELECT  1
                FROM  pm
                WHERE  mid = pmi.mid 
                  )
    LIMIT  1000 OFFSET 0;
```

I doubt if this will help much -- the query seems to need to touch virtually all rows in both tables.

If *all* `mid` values in pmi definitely exist in `pm`, then my `EXISTS` clause can be removed.  However you say that both tables have `PRIMARY KEY(mid)`?  I suspect `pmi` actually has a second column in its PK.  *Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`*.